# Wish Followed by Past Continuous and Past Simple

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, subjunctives, existentials

Yesterday I had and exam in English. I wondered very much for the following sentence - "I wish it ... (snow)now. It's Christmas". My question is if we can say "I wish it snowed now. It's Christmas" or it has to be "I wish it was snowing now. It's Christmas" and this is the only way it can go. I'll be very thankful if you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Well you wouldn't say "It snowed now." but rather "It is snowing now."

Therefore, you would say "I wish it was snowing now".

Similarly, you could say "It snowed yesterday", and you could also say "I wish it had snowed yesterday."

Comment: "He said it was snowing, but it didn't. If it had snowed, we would be seeing snow". Can you rephrase the sentence without would?